# Solving Systems of Linear Equations and coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I'm having trouble finding the coefficients in this equation based on knowing where a parabola passes through at certain points.

**Question:**

> By solving a system of $3$ equations in $3$ variables, find the coefficients in the equation of the parabola $y = \alpha + \beta x + \gamma x^2$ that passes through the points $(1, 1)$, $(2, 2)$ and $(3, 0)$.

Comment: We have $y=c(x-3)(x-b)$, from $1=-2c(1-b)$ and $2=-c(2-b)$ you'll be able to find $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have $$a+b+c=1$$
$$4a+2b+c=2$$
$$9a+3b+c=0$$
multiplying the first by $-4$ and adding to the second we get
$$2b+3c=2$$ (I)
multiplying the first by $$-9$$ and adding to the last one we get
$$6b+8c=9$$ (II)
multiplying $(I)$ by $-3$ and adding to (II) we get $$-c=3$$
can you proceed?

Comment: Wonderful! That makes it a whole lot easier. Thank you, my friend.

Comment: that is not me but it is the so called Gauss algorithm